# What is the difference between prayer and worship?

Tags: worship, translation-request, prayer

Since my sanskrit knowledge is very limited, I generally read the english translations. Here I often find words like 'prayer', and 'worship'. Is there any difference in their meaning?

Comment: Related: [What's the difference between puja (पूजा), vandana (वंदना) and stuti (स्तुति)](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10030/277).

Comment: prayer are casual remembrance of God but worshiping is intense prayers for some fruit from a Deity

Answer (score 6):

Prayer (प्रार्थना) - 'Can you please do this for me?'

Worship (पूजा) - 'Can I please do this for you?'

http://spokensanskrit.org

Comment: Iyer/Iyengars are smart.